# Unit Testing a nodejs function using `fs` wrapped in `promisify`

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, fs, node-promisify

In the following code I have a function that is looking for a file in the file system based on a provided configuration.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const lstat = promisify(fs.lstat);

async function doSomething(someFilePath) {
    try {
       const stats = await lstat(someFilePath);
    } catch (err) {
       throw err;
    }

    // do something with the file stats
}

module.exports = doSomething;
```

From here I'm trying to test the `doSomething` function but it fails because the file paths I'm providing don't actually exist. The below code *was* working when I was using `lstatSync` without `promisify`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const doSomething = require('./doSomething');

describe('The test', function() {

    let lstatStub;

    beforeEach(function() {
        lstatStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'lstatSync');
    });

    afterEach(function() { sinon.restore() });

    it('should pass', async function() {
        lstatStub.withArgs('image.jpg').returns({
            isFile: () => true,
            isDirectory: () => false,
        });

        assert(await doSomething('image.jpg')).ok();
    });

})
```

It now fails because `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'image.jpg'`. I've tried wrapping the stub in `promisify` or exporting the `promisify`ed functions into the test to stub. Both didn't work.

How do I stub a `promisify`ed `fs` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/)  and [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) package to stub `promisify` function.

E.g.

`main.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const lstat = promisify(fs.lstat);

async function doSomething(someFilePath) {
  return await lstat(someFilePath);
}

module.exports = doSomething;
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('61412987', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const lstatStub = sinon.stub().resolves('fake data');
    const utilStub = { promisify: sinon.stub().callsFake(() => lstatStub) };
    const doSomethng = proxyquire('./main', {
      util: utilStub,
    });

    const actual = await doSomethng('/root/avatar.jpg');
    expect(actual).to.be.equal('fake data');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(utilStub.promisify);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(lstatStub, '/root/avatar.jpg');
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  61412987
    ✓ should pass (1894ms)


  1 passing (2s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 main.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/61412987